# Find last matching entry in row based on column header info

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In my [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jnpiu0ufcCWISeVI0aFd-PXBhnYeGgFJPU_UkLPoWUs/edit?usp=sharing), a station ID is entered into range K9:9, and a serial number is automatically determined in the corresponding column in range K11:11 by finding the appropriate single letter that represents the station ID (identified on the Data sheet), and adding a sequential number after it.

[image: current formula]

This is the formula I am using to do this (entered into cell K11 and copied to all other cells in the row): `=IFERROR(CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(K$9,Data!$A$2:$B$7,2,FALSE),(TEXT(COUNTA(FILTER($K$9:K$9,LEFT($K$9:K$9,4)=LEFT(K$9,4))),"0"))),)`

However, this is not a typical case of serialization where all numbers are unique. When the numbers reach a certain point I need to be able to interrupt the sequence and restart the count by replacing a formula with a new serial number. For example, if I type M1 in cell Q11, I need the next serial number for this station to be M2 instead of the M5 I'm currently getting in cell W11. I realize I'm currently getting M5 due to using COUNTA.

How would I best perform a reverse lookup horizontally based on the header in the row the formula is in?

[image: goal]

Comment: Could you please provide clarification on your posted serial numbers, isn't it supposed to be unique? Do you also consider Apps Script or custom formula?

Comment: I attempted to clarify my situation in the original post. I generally prefer to use custom formulas, but am open to using Apps Script if it can provide a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

for `column_K` cell: `=xlookup(K$9,Data!$A:$A,Data!$B:$B)&1`

`column_L` and beyond: =

```
ifna(let(Σ,xlookup(L$9,Data!$A:$A,Data!$B:$B),
          Σ&regexextract(xlookup(Σ&"*",$K$11:K$11,$K$11:K$11,0,2,-1)&"","\d+")+1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using **Apps Script:** `OnEdit(e)` function so that the code will be triggered whenever a user edits a cell in google sheets.

**Suggestion:**

```
 function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var rowData = sheet.getRange(data.getRow(), data.getColumn(), 1, 32).getValues();
  const letter = rowData[0][0].split(/\d+/).filter(Boolean);
  var number = rowData[0][0].split(/\D+/).filter(Boolean);
  var count = parseInt(number);
  var result = rowData.map(x => x.map((y, i) => letter == y.split('')[0] & i != 0 ? letter + (count = count + 1) : y));
  
  sheet.getRange(data.getRow(), data.getColumn(), 1, 32).setValues(result);
}
```

The `map()` function used here is then used to loop over every element in the `rowData` variable.
For each element x, the nested `map()` method processes every element y in the x array. Now, If the current cell value starts with the same letter as the first cell (index 0) in the same row, the code concatenates the letter constant with the incremented count variable. Otherwise, the y value is left unchanged.

**RESULT:**
[image]

*Reference:*
[Map()](https://spreadsheet.dev/array-method-map-in-apps-script)